# How to swap View with long index gap in Kotlin?

Tags: swap

I can swap a view that I click, with other view that I can see. But when I want to swap a view that I click, with other view that I can't see, it refuses to swap. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should first do a swap for your list of items that you are dealing with, and then use `notifyItemMoved` for those indices. following code may help you:

```
val tmp = items[currentPos]
items[currentPos] = items[idx]
items[idx] = tmp
        
notifyItemMoved(currentPos, idx)
```

Comment: how about using ```notifyItemChanged(currentPos)``` and ```notifyItemChanged(idx)``` instead of ```notifyItemMoved(currentPos, idx)```

Comment: this should work. could you add your code?

Comment: just your swap function is enough I think. I think you could share it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248067/discussion-between-mrzbn-and-pleasedontbanme).